# Install all the files from a given folder with Powershell

Tags: powershell, installation, start-process

I was creating a script of Powershell as a hobby but it can be a tool to be used to install all the files from a given folder after a install from 0.
I'm struggling since I don't see where could be the problem. I'm new to PSH but I'm suspicious that it might be a data problem issue:

> Start-Process : Este comando no se puede ejecutar debido al error: El
> sistema no puede encontrar el archivo  especificado.
>
> En línea: 47 Carácter: 5
>
> - ```
>   Start-Process -FilePath "$installArrayMsi" -ArgumentList '/silent ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

The code:

```
$nameExe=Get-ChildItem | Where-Object -property name -Like "*.exe" | Get-ChildItem -name 
$nameMsi=Get-ChildItem | Where-Object -property name -Like "*.msi" | Get-ChildItem -name
$Location=(Get-Location).path
$Location

$numProgramsExe=$nameExe | Measure-Object -Line | Select-Object -Expand Lines
$numProgramsMsi=$nameMsi | Measure-Object -Line | Select-Object -Expand Lines


$superArrayExe = @($nameExe)

$installArrayExe = @(for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numProgramsExe; $i++)
{ 

    $Location+"\"+$superArrayExe[$i] 
}
)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numProgramsExe; $i++)
{ 
    Start-Process -FilePath "$installArrayExe" -ArgumentList '/silent', '/install' -Wait
    Write-Output "Instalando "$superArrayExe[$i]
    Write-Output "   "
}

$superArrayMsi = @($nameMsi)

$installArrayMsi = @(for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numProgramsMsi; $i++)
{ 

    $Location+"\"+$superArrayMsi[$i] 
}
)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numProgramsMsi; $i++)
{ 
    Start-Process -FilePath "$installArrayMsi" -ArgumentList '/silent', '/install' -Wait
    Write-Output "Instalando "$superArrayMsi[$i]
    Write-Output "   "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the trouble comes from the fact that a `.msi` file is not an executable file but a kind of database. You have to deploy it using the executable file [msiexec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options).

```
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "Your MSI file"
```

You can try something like

```
$params = '/i', "$installArrayMsi",
          'INSTALLDIR="$yourInstallDir"', 'ADSK_SETUP_EXE=1',
          '/qb!'
$p = Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList $params -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
$p.ExitCode
```

Comment: Great solution. Looks like a solution to the problem but it pops up the msiexec.exe menu:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8bTF.png

Comment: I'd like to say THANK YOU for your help. It eventually worked working with the nameMsi as an array that works inside the loop for for msi

Comment: @AlejandroBueno, if it helps put a +1 and please put your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that eventually worked well:

```
$nameMsi=@(Get-ChildItem | Where-Object -property name -Like "*.msi" | Get-ChildItem -name)

$numProgramsMsi=$nameMsi | Measure-Object -Line | Select-Object -Expand Lines

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numProgramsMsi; $i++)
{ 
    $params = '/i', $nameMsi[$i], '/qb!'
    $params
    $p = Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList $params -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
    $p.ExitCode
    Write-Output "Instalando "$superArrayMsi[$i]
    Write-Output "   "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So at the very end I found a better solution for this problem. I hope that it helps to beginners...and installs .Exe!

```
$nameExe=@(Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "*.exe"})
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $nameExe.Count; $i++)
{ 
    Start-Process -FilePath $nameExe.Name[$i] -ArgumentList '/silent', '/install' -Wait
    Write-Output "Instalando" $nameExe.Name[$i] "`n"
}
```